# Определение языка пользователя и загрузка соответствующего ему js-файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie, геолокация, перевод

Нужен скрипт для определения языка пользователя, в Google нашел вот это

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Для вывода страны -->
<div id="country"></div>




<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    ymaps.ready(function() {
      var country = ymaps.geolocation.country;


      $('#country').html('Ваша страна ' + country);

    });
  });
</script>
```

этот скрипт надо немного переделать.
например ваша страна **Россия** 
при входе на тот сайт, в котором будет определяться страна пользователя,
надо загрузить примерно вот такой скрипт `<script src="russian.js"></script>` который переводит какой-то язык на **Русский**

Например вот это скрипт

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        ymaps.ready(function()
        {
            var country = ymaps.geolocation.country;
            var city = ymaps.geolocation.city;

            $('#country').html('Ваша страна '+country);         
            $('#city').html('Ваш город '+city);
        });
    });
</script>
```

нам определяет страну пользователя, и выводит сюда как

```
<div id="country">Россия</div>
```

надо так сделать чтобы место слова **Россия** выводился скрипт 
`<script src="russian.js"></script>` в `<HEAD>`
и запомнить в куки

Comment: $('head').append('<script src="russian.js"></script>');  document.cookie = "country=russia"; при необходимости считывать куку.

Comment: @Jean-Claude а полный решение можно как куда ?

Comment: @Jean-Claude я вот так поставил не работает и еще на странице выводит скобки   `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
 {
        ymaps.ready(function()
  {
      var country = ymaps.geolocation.country;
   
      $('#country').html('Выша страна '+country);   
   $('head').append('<script src="russian.js"></script>')
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: К слову есть библиотека [globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize) (Одна из многих подобных) которая решает эту и многие другиe проблемы региональной адаптации...

Comment: @PeterSlusar это то что вы предлагаете на php а мой сайт не в php

Comment: Нет данная библиотека не является ничем иным как чистым javaScript плагином и подключаться на стороне клиента. Вот неплохая статья о использовании данной библиотеки : [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/os-jquerynewpart1/)

Comment: печально, но код страны не получить, мол RU, EN, IT, DE... а самое смешное, в замыкании [countryCode](http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU) есть

Answer (score 1):

Информацию о предпочитаемом языке можно получить из заголовка Accept-Language
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales.ru
Заголовок доступе только бэкенду, но ничто не мешает передать эту инфу в шаблон для использования ява-скриптом.